# Custom repository and specification

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

in a spring boot 3, i created a custom repository

```
@Repository
public class BookRepositoryCustomImpl  implements BookRepositoryCustom  {
}

public interface BookRepositoryCustom  {
      List<Book> searchBook(SearchBook searchBook);
}

@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

I search to use specification in searckBook method

Edit with spring 2.x it was possible

```
@Repository
public class AirportRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<Airport, Integer>
        implements AirportRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    public AirportRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em) {
        super(Airport.class, em);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Airport> advancedSearch(AirportSearch search, Pageable page) {
        Specification<Airport> specification = (Root<Airport> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq,
                CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {

            Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
            ...

            return p;

        };
        return this.findAll(specification, page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the [`JpaSpecificationExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) from within your custom method implementation.
But a `Specification` just creates a `Predicate` from a `Root`, a `CriteriaQuery`, and a `CriteriaBuilder`.
You can inject the `EntityManager` into `BookRepositoryCustomImpl`, and use the Criteria API to create a query including using the `Predicate` from a `Specification`.

Comment: It's new? because in spring 2.x i was possible in a custom repo like i show in my edit. So when we do a advance search we need to create the specification in the service layer now?

Comment: Fascinating ... I recommend to create an issue with Spring Data JPA then. We should at the very least have something in the migration guide about a change like this IFF it was intended.